# firestore/google api get_document hangs sporadically with apache

Tags: apache, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, apache2.4

I'm trying to deploy my django project with firebase backend.

But when I try to read document from firestore, document.get() **hangs indefinitely**. And it happens **sporadically**. The issue happens *only* with apache so far. I have tried with nginx, development server and django shell, but no issues. I have checked further into the firebase package and issue is happening at [get_document](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/72c127545b009dfd10032b20c3407bf6c3a389b8/firestore/google/cloud/firestore_v1/gapic/firestore_client.py#L253). I couldn't go into further details.

Please find the versions of the packages used

```
firebase-admin 3.2.0
google-api-core 1.14.3
apache Apache/2.4.29
django 2.2.8
Ubuntu 18.04.3LTS 64bit 4.15.0-58-generic
python 3.6.9
```

Can you please help me solve the problem? Or could it be an issue with apache and need to raise an issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, I have same issue and don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I have deployed with [nginx](https://unit.nginx.org/installation/) and [gunicorn](https://pypi.org/project/gunicorn/), no issues. Should we raise an issue in apache? But I'm not sure what(apache or mod_wsgi) is causing the issue.